# "Opposite" of IReadOnlyList to only allow collections that can be modified / are writeable?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for an interface that would only allow me to store write-able collections like List but not compile if I tried to give it a non write-able one like an array.

I tried both `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>` but **arrays implement both of those** (for some reason).

```
ICollection<Foo> foo = new Foo[0]; // Compiles happily
IList<Bar> bar = new Bar[0]; // Compiles happily

foo.Add(null); // Throws
bar.Add(null); // Throws

// Is there an interface that would only allow write-able collections?
```

I know I can check `IsReadOnly` before calling `Add` but this is pretty awful. Am I out of luck?
I tried to search online but didn't find anything relevant.

**EDIT:** So far from what I've gathered, the **least worse option** would seem to be to stick with `List` directly? But my intent was to not force the implementation type to a concrete class unless I had to. :/

Comment: @aybe no, no, I know that and what you say makes sense. I just don't want something that can't be modified. So I only care about the ability to write or not. Reading is given in almost all situations (almost :D ).

Comment: I think you just have to live with that fact and move forward, an interface specifies a contract, but an implementation does not necessarily has to fully implement it, e.g. a stream is not necessarily seekable. It is expected that you'd check your arguments, throw accordingly and most importantly, write the documentation of your types.

Comment: @aybe But that means no compile-time protection which seriously suck. Hence why IMO, the least worse option would be to stick to List instead but that kinda sucks too (but differently).

Comment: Look, ultimately, there's nothing you can do about it, you can't expect to modify .NET for this so, keep on coding and advance in your project; I'm pretty sure at some point you'll hit another wall that will make this one totally irrelevant because it is, really.

Comment: An `Array` _is_ writable, as in you can _modify_ the elements. That's what "writable" means. You want a collection to which you can add elements. That's something different.... _Why_ do you want to be generic? Being overly generic when unnecessary is not good. It "complects" your code. If you want a List, use a List.

Comment: Bear in mind, an implementation of an interface may in fact just have no-ops hiding behind most members. If you need a collection with certain definitely implemented members (and any other requirements), create an instance of that collection yourself. Allow your callers to give you anything enumerable and then expose events that you think that callers may care about when you modify *your* collection.

Comment: The opposite of read-only would be a list that you can only add to but you can't read. You can do that with an `Add` method that doesn't do anything - there would be no way to tell the difference.

Answer (score 3):

I think in this instance you could deal with this by specifying an interface of your own, e.g.

```
IWriteableCollection<T> : ICollection<T> {
      void Add(T item);
}
```

I know that this involves a custom type and a certain amount of coding around it would be needed, but does give you compile time safety.

An implementation might be something like:

```
WriteableFooCollection : IWriteableColection<Foo>, List<Foo> {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, so you would have to write new classes for each general collection... and `List` itself will not work. So it's not exactly what the OP asks. (What he wants can't be done simply]

Comment: @JHBonarius - I appreciate that it's not _exactly_ what he is looking for, but given that there is no good simple answer to his question, then this is, at least, a possible approach.

Comment: Interesting! Ans since "user-defined" conversion are, unfortunately  , forbidden from/to base types, I guess the next best thing would be to use an extension on each of those generics to "convert" them to this new base type. Still convoluted but as JHBonarius said, there isn't much I can do about it so I appreciate the input. 

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to chose from

1. Just use a plain `List<T>`, this have less flexibility, but is adequate for the majority of cases in my experience.
2. Use `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>` and just live with the problem that it will fail if the collection do not implement the full interface. It might help if you consistently use `IEnumerable<T>` / `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` / `IReadOnlyList<T>` if you are *not* adding to the collection, since that help indicate that anything else is for writing to. You might also want to check the [ÌReadOnlyFlag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.isreadonly?view=net-6.0), this would be a runtime check, but it might help to provide a better error message.
3. Use `Action<T>`, If you *only* need to add values, you can just give a delegate to the add method, i.e. `AddValuesToCollection(myCollection.Add)`